# Formula to count the number of matching data in a column

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains thousands of rows of data. One of the column contains a country where the order was placed. **Is it possible to count and output how many of each country there is?**

It can be done using `=COUNTIF(A2:A8,"UK")` but obviously that counts "UK" specifically. Is there a way to do it without putting in a specific country name?

Output wise, it'd be good if it could be:

- UK 10
- France 3
- Germany 12

Comment: Just replace "UK" with a cell reference. Or use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect occasion for creating a pivot table from your data.

Select your data -> Insert -> Pivot Table

In the fields list menu:

Place Country in 'Rows'

Place OrderID/ (or something else that always has a value in a given order) in 'values' and make sure it is set to 'count of OrderID' and not 'sum or average of OrderID'.